# ADAL.js token renewal with ExtJS application

Tags: javascript, azure, extjs, adal, adal.js

I am trying to implement ADAL.js against Azure AD into my ExtJS application (SPA). This works up to the point where the first token expires and should be renewed.

I have made a fiddle:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27oc

Steps to reproduce:

- Enter your tenant and app id.
- Click "Login". The login popup opens.
- Login. You now have to set the redirect Url in your app in Azure portal as per the small gray error message at the bottom.
- Close the popup window.
- Click "Login" again. The login popup open again. Log in.
- Check that a token is present by clicking "Show token".
- To not have to wait an hour, click "Invalidate token (expire it)".
- Then, click "Renew token" to acquire a new token from the login server.
- Wait 6 seconds and find that the following error is thrown:

  > Token renewal operation failed due to timeout

In Network tab, I see that during the token renewal, a call to login.microsoftonline.com forwards to

```
https://fiddle.sencha.com/local/15071063979572828477/#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkhIQnlLVS0wRHFBcU1aaDZaRlBkMlZXYU90ZyIsImtpZCI6IkhIQnlLVS0wRHFBcU1aaDZaRlBkMlZXYU90ZyJ9.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...
```

which means that the token comes back from the server, but it is not correctly processed on the client side. Am I missing something important there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timing out of the token renewal may happen due to a few different reasons. This is documented in the ADAL.js [FAQ](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/wiki/FAQs#q7-token-renewal-operation-failed-due-to-timeout).

Looking at the fiddle provided, the reason for the error in this case may be that the `handleWindowCallback` is not being called. You can see an example of this in this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/blob/master/TodoSPA/App/Scripts/app.js#L23).